# Moq Mock Unit Test: A Moq Mock Setup with an instance, and the SUT business code with another instance but both have same content. Why does it fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Here is info about our technical development environment :

•   .NET 6

•   C# 10

•   Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version 15.5.0

•   Moq Version 4.18.2

•   Xunit Version 2.4.1

> ```
> public class Vehicle  {
>      public string VIN { get; set; }
>      public string CarCompany { get; set; }
>      public string Model  { get; set; }
> }
> ```

> ```
> public interface IBlahClient : IDisposable {
>              
>   Task<TResponse> SendQuery<TResponse>( string aVehicleJsonString, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
>
>  }
> ```

> ```
> public class BlahClient : IBlahClient {
>
>        public Task<TResponse> SendQuery<TResponse>( string aVehicleJsonString,  
> CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
>     {
>
>          Return ……;
>     } 
>  }
> ```

> ```
>  public class VehicleProcessor {
>
>     public static string ConvertToJSON( Vehicle aVehicle ){
>              …….blah blah blah blah code…..
>             return aVehicleJsonString;
>
>          }
> ```

> ```
> public string SendVehicleInfoToDMV( IBlahClient client, Vehicle aVehicle ){
>             string aVehicleJsonString = ConvertToJSON(aVehicle );
>               
>             string response = client. SendQuery<string>(  aVehicleJsonString, CancellationToken.None);
>
>              return response;
>  }
> ```
>
> }

> ```
>  public class VehicleProcessorSUTClass {
>        [Fact]
>         public void Test()
>         {
>                   
>                  Vehicle aVehicle = ..…BlahBlah Code for instantiating a Vehicle instance…..
>                 
>                 string aVehicleJsonString = VehicleProcessor.ConvertToJSON( aVehicle );
>
>                     VehicleProcessor aVehicleProcessorSUT = new VehicleProcessor();
>                 
>          Mock<IBlahClient> blahClientMock = new Mock<IBlahClient>();
>
>                    blahClientMock.Setup(c => c.SendQuery<string>(aVehicleJsonString , CancellationToken.None))
>                          .Returns(aVehicleJsonString);
>
>                  string response = aVehicleProcessorSUT. SendVehicleInfoToDMV(blahClientMock.Object, aVehicle );
>                //// Unfortunately response turns out to be null /////
>               } }
> ```

I understand that the complex subtle nuance of invoking the ConvertToJSON at 2 times which will result in 2 different json string instances with the same content:

1. in the Moq Test code I invoke the ConvertToJSON , and use the result for the blahClientMock's SendQuery method's Moq setup.
2. Within the actual SUT's business code itself, I invoke the ConvertToJSON

However, even though there are 2 different instances of aVehicleJsonString , they both still have the same content.  Why does the SUT business code return null when it is unit tested?

Comment: None of the code shown matches.  The interface and implementation shown don't match. The mock setup also does not match the original interface. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then edit the question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is actually being asked.

Comment: @Nkosi There is No async code.  In C# async code will contain a method with the async C# key term placed before it's name. The BlahClient does return a task, but it's Still Synchronous. Also, I've fixed the other problems that you raised now.

Comment: Sigh, the shown code wont compile because you are not telling the mock to return a Task as defined by the interface. That aside, if you dont provide actual code then we can only guess at what the actual problem is. Hence my original XY statement

Answer (score 1):

From the code you've provided, there are a few things that stand out which could be causing the issue:

1. **Mismatched Method Names**: In your `IBlahClient` interface, you have a method named `SendQueryAsync`, but in your `VehicleProcessor` class, you're calling a method named `SendQuery`. This will result in a compile-time error. Ensure that the method names match.
2. **Async/Await Pattern**: The `SendQueryAsync` method is asynchronous, but you're not using the `await` keyword when calling it in the `VehicleProcessor` class. This means you're not actually getting the result of the method, but rather a `Task` object. You should await the method to get the result.
3. **Mocking Setup**: When you set up your mock, you're using the method `SendQuery<dynamic>`, but the actual method in the interface is `SendQueryAsync<TResponse>`. This means your mock setup might not be matching the actual method call, hence the mock doesn't return the expected value and you get `null`.

I've provided an updated version of the relevant parts:

1. Update the `VehicleProcessor` class to use `await`:

```cs
public async Task<string> SendVehicleInfoToDMV(IBlahClient client, Vehicle aVehicle)
{
    string aVehicleJsonString = ConvertToJSON(aVehicle);
    string response = await client.SendQueryAsync<string>(aVehicleJsonString, CancellationToken.None);
    return response;
}
```

2. Update your test method to match the correct method and use async/await:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
{
    Vehicle aVehicle = ...; // Your code for instantiating a Vehicle instance
    string aVehicleJsonString = VehicleProcessor.ConvertToJSON(aVehicle);
    VehicleProcessor aVehicleProcessorSUT = new VehicleProcessor();

    Mock<IBlahClient> blahClientMock = new Mock<IBlahClient>();
    blahClientMock.Setup(c => c.SendQueryAsync<string>(aVehicleJsonString, CancellationToken.None))
                  .ReturnsAsync(aVehicleJsonString);

    string response = await aVehicleProcessorSUT.SendVehicleInfoToDMV(blahClientMock.Object, aVehicle);
    Assert.Equal(aVehicleJsonString, response); // Add this assertion to check if the response matches the expected value
}
```

3. Ensure that the `BlahClient` class correctly implements the `SendQueryAsync` method from the `IBlahClient` interface.

These changes I provided for your test should work as expected. If you still encounter issues, ensure that the `ConvertToJSON` method is deterministic and produces the same JSON string for the same input.

Answer (score 1):

Given the incomplete originally provided interface, the following will be used for the purpose of this example

```
public interface IBlahClient : IDisposable {
         
    TResponse SendQuery<TResponse>( string aVehicleJsonString, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

}
```

Along with the following subject under test

```
public string SendVehicleInfoToDMV(IBlahClient client, Vehicle aVehicle ) {
    string aVehicleJsonString = ConvertToJSON(aVehicle );
          
    string response = client. SendQuery<string>(aVehicleJsonString, CancellationToken.None);

    return response;
}
```

When setting up a mock in MOQ with an **explicit reference type** the mock expects that **same reference** that was provided during setup. If it does not get the same reference, then the default behavior is to return `null`.

To get around such issues, Argument Matchers, can be used

```
[Fact]
public void Test() {
    //Arrange
    Vehicle aVehicle = //..…BlahBlah Code for instantiating a Vehicle instance…..
            
    string aVehicleJsonString = VehicleProcessor.ConvertToJSON( aVehicle );

    VehicleProcessor aVehicleProcessorSUT = new VehicleProcessor();
            
    Mock<IBlahClient> blahClientMock = new Mock<IBlahClient>();

    blahClientMock
        .Setup(c => c.SendQuery<string>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(aVehicleJsonString);

    //Act
    string response = aVehicleProcessorSUT. SendVehicleInfoToDMV(blahClientMock.Object, aVehicle);
           
    //Assert
    //....
}
```

If an exact match is required, then the matcher can be changed accordingly

```
[Fact]
public void Test() {
    //Arrange
    Vehicle aVehicle = //..…BlahBlah Code for instantiating a Vehicle instance…..
            
    string aVehicleJsonString = VehicleProcessor.ConvertToJSON( aVehicle );

    VehicleProcessor aVehicleProcessorSUT = new VehicleProcessor();
            
    Mock<IBlahClient> blahClientMock = new Mock<IBlahClient>();

    blahClientMock
        .Setup(c => c.SendQuery<string>(It.Is<string>(s => s == aVehicleJsonString), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(aVehicleJsonString);

    //Act
    string response = aVehicleProcessorSUT. SendVehicleInfoToDMV(blahClientMock.Object, aVehicle);
           
    //Assert
    //....
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)